# Is it possible to use a variable as part of an image URL?

Tags: php, html, image

I am making a quiz on a basic website using PHP and HTML/CSS and have answers stored in a PHP array.

I would like to display the quiz answers and the corresponding images (which I have named to match) using the simplest method.
For example if $ANSWER="cat", I want to display "cat.jpg"

If it were possible to use a variable in the image URL it would be wonderful, but I haven't been able to find an example of this.

Should this syntax work?

```
echo '<img src=/pictures/"$ANSWER".jpg >';
```

So far I'm getting no output but not sure if it's due to a bug somewhere else.

Comment: you'll most likely need to rename (or match) the current file name to the same name as the value name of the variable, or make a mapping of some sort. `$answers = array('cat' => 'path/to/image/fat-cat.png')`, then use it as `echo "<img src=\"/pictures/{$answers[$answer]}.jpg\" />` be careful with the answer and try to sanitize

Comment: and by the way, you'll need to turn around those quotes, wrap them inside double quotes to interpolate the variable value inside the string

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, Ghost.  I went with Rahul's answer because it was simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
echo "<img src='/pictures/".$ANSWER.".jpg' >";
```

or

```
<img src="/pictures/<?php edho $ANSWER;?>.jpg">
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This worked perfectly.                                         echo "<img src='/pictures/".$ANSWER.".jpg' >";

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Rahul's answer:

PHP is server side meaning the page is not rendered until all of the PHP has resolved on the server.

That's why his answer works. The server gets

```
echo "<img src='/pictures/".$ANSWER.".jpg' />";
```

resolves $ANSWER to whatever the variable is set to and provides to the client side:

```
<img src='/pictures/my_answer.jpg' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try to use double quotes like:
`echo "<img src='/pictures/".$ANSWER.".jpg' >";`

or still use single quote like:

```
echo '<img src=\'/pictures/'.$ANSWER.'.jpg \'>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi :) Hope this helps :)

```
<?php 
$ANSWER="cat";
?>
<img src="pictures/<?php echo "$ANSWER.jpg"; ?>">
```

Proven and tested :)